# How to open two (renamed) instances of a single instance application? VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created a single-instance application for two different companies. After renaming the solution, namespace, assembly and everything I cannot still run both applications simultaneously. What is the reason behind this since things the apps had in common have been renamed?

Comment: What is your logic of making sure of only one instance of the application? Changing assembly name and namespaces won't help I guess. You need to work with the logic.

Comment: Are you using a named mutex to see if there is only one instance running? If so, check that the name is unique to the application.

Comment: If you uses `Make single instance application` feature in project settings -and startup is set to the "MainForm" - then try to change name of that "MaintForm" too.

Comment: Yes I had used the 'Make single instance application' feature. And I have changed the name of the startup form too but it doesn't help.